# In java, i cant set two of the same variables to different values, but in python i can?

Tags: java, python, variables

Why cant I set two of the same variables such as "X" to be 4 and 19, such as

```
int x = 4;
int x = 19;
```

and this will give me an error.

But in python, I can do this and it wont give me an error.

```
x = 4
x = 19
```

It is because java is compiling, while python is interpreting?

Comment: Why would you even expect two completely different languages to behave the same? Also you don't have *"two of the same variable"* - that wouldn't even make sense, how would you distinguish them?

Comment: You cannot have two variables with the same name in any language. In python you are reassigning the same variable x to 19. In Java to do this you will simply say `x = 19;` for the second line.

Answer (score 5):

In Java, the line `int x = 4` is creating the variable. You cannot recreate a variable. Here is what you do instead:

```
int x = 4;
x = 19;
```

That allows you to declare the variable, then without the `int` change the variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

Because in case of Java, you're trying to assign same name to 2 variables. What you are doing is variable declaration in Java.

But Python on the other hand, considers that as variable assignment and if that variable does not exists, it allocates memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning the variable x from 4 to 19.

Answer (score 0):

Your example won't work in java because you are declaring the variable twice. 
To change a variable in java you don't need to add the 'int' identifier on both the first time it is declared AND when you change it. You add the 'int' identifier ONLY when you are declaring the variable for the first time.

Your code should look more like this:

```
int x = 4;
x = 19;
```